# Me too or me neither to agree with never doing something

Tags: neither, too

Is it me too or me either to say that I also never do something?

I never work on Sundays.
Me too

or

me neither.

Comment: I would say "Nor me."

Comment: A search for "me too or me neither" will probably give you the answer. Have you tried that? If you have, please [edit] your question to tell us what you found, and what you're still unsure about.

Comment: [***Me either***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22him+me+either%22) and ***Me neither*** aren't uncommon in casual AmE contexts, but they'd be unlikely in BrE.

Comment: In response to "I never work on Sunday" you could say **Nor do I**,  **Me neither**  or **Neither do I**.  In any case I believe it is better to respond to a negative statement by continuing the negative rather than switching to a positive form.